# Altering NSObject Definition resulting in unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsobject

I'm attempting to customise an `NSObject` to accept an additional parameter, however whenever I attempt to add this I get:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[TEATimeRange initWithStart:end:fill:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
```

Here is the `.h` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TEATimeRange : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSDate *start;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *end;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *fill;

+ (instancetype)timeRangeWithStart:(NSDate *)startTime end:(NSDate *)endTime fill:(UIColor *)fillColor;

- (id)initWithStart:(NSDate *)startTime end:(NSDate *)endTime fill:(UIColor *)fillColor;

@end
```

and the `.m` file:

```
#import "TEATimeRange.h"

@implementation TEATimeRange

+ (instancetype)timeRangeWithStart:(NSDate *)startTime end:(NSDate *)endTime fill:(UIColor *)fillColor
{
    return [[TEATimeRange alloc] initWithStart:startTime end:endTime fill:fillColor];
}

- (id)initWithStart:(NSDate *)startTime end:(NSDate *)endTime fill:(UIColor *)fillColor
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _start = startTime;
        _end = endTime;
        _fill = fillColor;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Calling Instance (in Swift):

```
TEATimeRange(start: someDateTime, end: someDateTime?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(someTime)), fill: .orange)
```

If I remove the references to `fill:` it runs as expected, so I'm confused as to why.

I have attempted a SO search, but as I only have 3 days experience with iOS development, I haven't been able to find any solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated. (Even if it's a silly thing!)

Comment: Your code compiles but you get this error at runtime? This shouldn't help but change `id` to `instancetype` for your `init...` method. Also, show the code that is creating the `TEATimeRange` instance.

Comment: I just added your class exactly as-is to a test iOS project. A line such as `TEATimeRange *range = [TEATimeRange timeRangeWithStart:[NSDate date] end:[NSDate date] fill:[UIColor redColor]];` built and ran with no error.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question with the relevant creation instance, please note that the caller is in swift vs objc

Comment: Are you sure your updated `.m` file is included in your target app and re-compiled?

Comment: @OOPer I've cleaned my build folder and re-built it. Is that what you are referring to? And yes, the `TEAChart` parent is imported in the target app `UIViewController` file

Comment: Maybe no. You have said nothing about `TEAChart` in your question and I cannot answer anything about such thing. And _I've cleaned my build folder and re-built it._ is not what I'm referring. That does not guarantee your `.m` file to be re-compiled.

Comment: @OOPer how strange! I've just cleaned the build folder, closed xcode and restarted and suddenly it works... Why is that, will I have to do this everytime?

Comment: @OOPer sorry for clarity, `TEAChart` is the parent `.h` file which imports all the sub classes `TEATimeRange` plus a couple of custom views. `TEAChart` is also the defined module that is imported into my swift files. In the future, how can I guarantee that an `.m` file is recompiled if I need to make other changes?

Comment: Xcode show some weird behaviors, especially when working with frameworks. What you have tried is one of what you should try, when you have imported some modules and the source code update not in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future devs that hit this page, my issue was resolved by the following:

1. Clean Build Folder (Product > Clean Build Folder or <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>)
2. Restarting Xcode
3. Re-Running the application

See comments above from @OOPer and @rmaddy for further guidance if this does not work

Comment: This works because the property you added is an Interface Builder (IB) object and the major of cases needs to clean the build folder, try adding a new property like NSString or NSInteger, well done and play with the code :) cheers